# Traversing the children of a task_struct

Tags: c, kernel

Below I have the code where Im trying to check if a pid( given before) is found in one of the childrens of my current task. I have already initialized the current struct (current_task) and I am checking all its children, in theory. I cant find my mistake and the compiling of the kernel takes too much (~1h) to try and change many things. Any help/tips would be appreciated.

```
                    struct list_head children_tasks;
                    struct task_struct * child_task;

                    children_tasks = current_task->children;

                    if(children_tasks==NULL)
                            return EINVAL;

                    list_for_each(children_tasks, &current_task->children)
                    {
                            child_task = list_entry(&children_tasks, struct task_struct, sibling);
                            if(pid == child_task->pid)
                            {
                                    printk("ok");
                                    return 1;
                            }

                    }
```

Compiler Errors:

```
    include/linux/list.h:370:11: error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct list_head' from type 'struct list_head *'
  for (pos = (head)->next; prefetch(pos->next), pos != (head); \
           ^
kernel/set_period_parameters.c:47:4: note: in expansion of macro 'list_for_each'
    list_for_each(children_tasks, &current_task->children)
    ^
include/linux/list.h:370:39: error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'struct list_head')
  for (pos = (head)->next; prefetch(pos->next), pos != (head); \
                                       ^
kernel/set_period_parameters.c:47:4: note: in expansion of macro 'list_for_each'
    list_for_each(children_tasks, &current_task->children)
    ^
include/linux/list.h:370:52: error: invalid operands to binary != (have 'struct list_head' and 'struct list_head *')
  for (pos = (head)->next; prefetch(pos->next), pos != (head); \
                                                    ^
kernel/set_period_parameters.c:47:4: note: in expansion of macro 'list_for_each'
    list_for_each(children_tasks, &current_task->children)
    ^
include/linux/list.h:370:46: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
  for (pos = (head)->next; prefetch(pos->next), pos != (head); \
                                              ^
kernel/set_period_parameters.c:47:4: note: in expansion of macro 'list_for_each'
    list_for_each(children_tasks, &current_task->children)
    ^
include/linux/list.h:371:19: error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'struct list_head')
          pos = pos->next)
                   ^
kernel/set_period_parameters.c:47:4: note: in expansion of macro 'list_for_each'
    list_for_each(children_tasks, &current_task->children)
```

Comment: *I cant find my mistake* What is happening? What is the behavior that makes you think you have a mistake?

Comment: i hit compiler errors. ill add them now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro is expecting a pointer, but `children_tasks` is allocated as an object (struct).  You might try prefixing it with `&`.  Specifically,

```
list_for_each( &children_tasks, &current_task->children)
```

I have no idea if the rest is right, but this does look like the cause of the compile errors.

Comment: I changed children_tasks to task_struct * and also changed this line 
'children_tasks = current_task->children;'
to this
'children_tasks = &current_task->children;'
now i hit no comp errors, so im guessing i got confused with the pointers there.